# How to create different sections of post in drupal 7

Tags: content-management-system, drupal-7, editing

still new to drupal 7. I've read a couple of things on how drupal works. I don't quite get some things though. How do I create articles for different categories? Like I would like to make articles to be listed under graphics, then articles under html/css or under 3D,etc. How to categorize them in the main menus? And how different is this to the blogging module or book module? I know this may have been posted similarly here, but I would just want a simple explanation not found in long chapters. Thanks guys.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to use taxonomy for categories and in article add a field for category from cotegories vocabulary.
For displaying I'll suggest Views module (http://drupal.org/project/views)